# React Axios post Oauth2 username and password fails on FastAPI backend

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm quite baffled how this is happening:

Here is my CURL request that works

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/auth/token" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "username=blah&password=blah"
```

The same in React using Axios does not fly. I get this warning

```
xhr.js:177 POST https://localhost:8000/auth/token net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

```js
const params = qs.stringify({
      'username': userName,
      'password': password
    });
    console.log(params);
    const headers = {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    axios.post("https://localhost:8000/auth/token", params, headers,
    ).then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        console.log(result.data);
        setAuthTokens(result.data);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log("Login error");
      console.log(e.request);
      setIsError(true);
    });
  }
```

Can someone please help. If it's of any help here is my FastAPI /auth/token method

```
def login(response: Response , username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    email = username
    user = load_user(email)
    if not user:
        print("User blah")
        raise InvalidCredentialsException
    elif password != user['password']:
        raise InvalidCredentialsException
    access_token = manager.create_access_token(
        data = dict(sub=email)
    )
    return {'access_token': access_token, 'token_type': 'bearer'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It so happens I had specified https instead of http in the react code.

```
 axios.post("https://localhost:8000/auth/token", params, headers,
```

Should be

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/auth/token", params, headers,
```